# An Alternative to the Android-Emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I know I could use my Desire Z as a test phone, but what if I want to develop for 3.0 Honeycomb? What's an alternative for the emulator since it's so slow?

Comment: Use a tablet with HoneyComb...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.bluestacks.com/

This site has been getting some press recently. It seems that they are going to launch a windows runnable version of android later this year. This will be another alternative to using devices or emulators for testing I would imagine.

Comment: Will be ... alpha release is October 11.

Comment: Does BlueStacks emulate HoneyComb? Last time I checked, it's still Android 2.3 only.

Comment: @sm4 No idea. Honestly blue stacks lost me at "PLease sign in with your facebook account to continue" Hopefully they've removed that requirement by now. But that is how it was when they launched and I decided it was a joke and never looked back at it again.

Comment: @FoamyGuy I see :) Nowadays, Genymotion is gaining more publicity (they want your email instead). But Bluestacks is still the way to test on 2.3. Login is of course required to get your contact details to keep you engaged - since Android is all about everything-for-free-but-not-really strategy ;)

Answer (score 1):

A general solution to the slowness of processor-emulation based emulators is to run a build of the embedded environment compiled for the same processor and general architecture as the hosting machine, in virtual machine software which can run most of the code native, and only has to trap and emulate privileged/hardware-related actions.

In other words, you run the x86 build of android in VirtualBox, vmware, or whatever, and dispense with the overhead of emulating an arm processor.

In quick web searching I'm not getting a confident answer if there's a working build of Honeycomb for x86 yet, but presumably there will be a build of that or a later android version at some point.

Comment: Source code of Honeycomb is closed (at this time), so we'll see such builds not not soon

Comment: Yes, it appears it may only come with a later version

Answer (score 0):

The only alternative is to have a physical device with Android 3.0 imaged on it.

Comment: Oh, I see, So like the Motorola Xoom, or Galaxy tab 10.1, I'm assuming

Comment: This answer may be true at the moment but will be incorrect in the long term once honeycomb gains more ports, particularly to x86.

Comment: Until then, I guess I'll just stick to 2.3 as a means of mobile programming.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one for a change it actually provides an eclipse plugin and it uses cloud i guess it is faster than the emulator comes with android by default http://www.genymotion.com/features/